# eZPublish - how to get Selection value?

Tags: ezpublish

I created (in admin) a selection field called `color`. Now I can't access it. When I run `{$note.data_map.color.content|attribute(show)}` it prints `value`. But I can't access it without `attribute(show)`. What can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

eZSelection's `content` is an array, access the `0` key on `content` to get the value.

`{$node.data_map.email_option.content.0}`

Comment: this gives the `id` of the selection, not the value. How can i get the value?

Answer (score 1):

1. don't forget you always have attribute_view_gui* which can help you quite a lot in these cases.
2. you can set the attribute to be information collector and collect that information from user.

*{attribute_view_gui attribute=$node.data_map.color}

Answer (score 0):

You need to match the option array defined in your class attribute with the id of the selected option in order to get the value of it.

`$node.data_map.color.class_content.options` will contain all the options available (associative array with `id` and `name` values)

`$node.data_map.color.content` is an array containing the ids of the selected options (because this field can handle multiple selection).

Even if the `{section}` function is deprecated I'll suggested that you have a look at the default template rendering an `ezselection` attribute : `design/standard/templates/content/datatype/view/ezselection.tpl`

Answer (score 0):

If you have "Multiple choice" type than you can do it like this:

```
{if $node.data_map.color.has_content}
    {foreach $node.data_map.color.content as $colorID}
        {foreach $node.data_map.color.class_content.options as $opt}
            {cond($opt.id|eq($colorID), $opt.name, '')}
        {/foreach}
    {/foreach}
{/if}
```